# Validate nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have OpenID auth on my app and email is not required by default, but if user creates request I need to validate presence of email.

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :request, dependent: :destroy
  validates :email, format: { with: Devise.email_regexp, allow_blank: true }
end
```

I already tried two variants, but they are do not work and validation messages are not shown.

The first:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, if: ->(u) { u.request.present? }
end
```

The second:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_user_email

  def validate_user_email
    self.user.errors.add(:email, :blank) if self.user.email.blank?
  end
end
```

Can somebody advise something workable? Thanks!

Comment: Strange, your first approach is correct. Something else must be going on. How do you try to check if it works?

Comment: You say that the attributes are nested. What does you form look like?

Comment: @agis, I use pry for debug. The first version makes loading from the database for fetching Request which does not exist there yet.

Comment: @jason-carty, the form code:
`
= simple_form_for(@request, html: { class: 'custom' }) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :user_id, as: :hidden
    = f.simple_fields_for :user do |ff|
      = ff.input :email
`